# how can I optimize a query with multiple joins (already have indexes)?

Tags: mysql, optimization

```
SELECT citing.article_id as citing, lac_a.year, r.id_when_cited, cited_issue.country, citing.num_citations
FROM isi_lac_authored_articles as lac_a
    JOIN isi_articles citing ON (lac_a.article_id = citing.article_id)
    JOIN isi_citation_references r ON (citing.article_id = r.article_id)
    JOIN isi_articles cited ON (cited.id_when_cited = r.id_when_cited) 
    JOIN isi_issues cited_issue ON (cited.issue_id = cited_issue.issue_id);
```

I have indexes on all the fields being JOINED on.

Is there anything I can do? My tables are large (some 1 Million records, the references tables has 500 million records, the articles table has 25 Million).

This is what EXPLAIN has to say:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type   | possible_keys                                                            | key                                   | key_len | ref                           | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cited_issue | ALL    | NULL                                                                     | NULL                                  | NULL    | NULL                          | 1156856 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cited       | ref    | isi_articles_id_when_cited,isi_articles_issue_id                         | isi_articles_issue_id                 | 49      | func                          |      19 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r           | ref    | isi_citation_references_article_id,isi_citation_references_id_when_cited | isi_citation_references_id_when_cited | 17      | mimir_dev.cited.id_when_cited |       4 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | lac_a       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                  | PRIMARY                               | 16      | mimir_dev.r.article_id        |       1 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | citing      | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                  | PRIMARY                               | 16      | mimir_dev.r.article_id        |       1 |             |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+---------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

Comment: What database type are you using? That's a pretty simple SQL statement. Are you using myisam or innodb?

Comment: myisam. Its simple SQL, but the tables are large. the first line of the EXPLAIN output has 1M rows... can I avoid this type of thing by splitting up my query? Or something else?

Comment: Where does the result of the query go? Very roughly, it should return not less than 100Mb of data. What do you do with the result?

Comment: this is not for an application. I am doing analysis with the data. The result goes into R/SPPS/Excel.

Comment: Are you trying to "invetigate" the data to do analytics or are you already knowing what you are looking for within the data?  I am writing an article on investigative & iterative queries.  The approach here is the issue.  I would love to talk with you about this and hep you find the best solution for your task.  My email address is in my profile.  If you email me, I can respond back with contact info.

Comment: Can you change the data structure here at all?  Are you manually running these queries and pulling the data into your environment or are you letting a process run that exports that data into some other file?

Comment: I believe I know what this data is for from what I remember reading in the news about 5 or 6 years ago.

Comment: I am trying to extract data that I know is in there. The data structure is quite simple. I am getting in touch by email with some details and we can coordinate there. Thanks Craig!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you realy need all the returned data, I would suggest two things:

1. You, probably, know the data better than MySQL and you can try to make advantage of it if MySQL is not correct in its assumptions. Currently, MySQL thinks that it is easier to full scan the whole `isi_issues` table at the beginning, and if the result is really going to include all issues, than the assumption is correct. But if there are many issues that should not be in the result, you may want to force another order of the joins that you consider more correct. It is you, who knows which table applies the strongest restrictions and which are the smallest to full scan (you will anyway need to full scan something, since there is no WHERE clause).
2. You can make profit from covering indexes (that is indexes that contain enough data in itself and not needing to touch the row data). For example, having an index (article_id, num_citations) on `isi_articles` and (article_id, year) on `isi_lac_authored_articles` and even (country) on `isi_issues` will significantly speed up that query as long as the indexes fit in memory, but, from the other side, will make you indexes larger and slightly slow dow inserts into the table.

Comment: on point 1. I do know that it wont be making use of all the issues. how do I force it to do that JOIN last? The only table I want to full scan is the first one (isi_lac_authored_articles).

Comment: @pocketfullofcheese, look at the `STRAIGHT_JOIN` in MySQL docs:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

Comment: i'm trying this out, but it does not seem that it is getting much faster. How can I check what is happening? Is there any way to check a query's progress?

Comment: @pocketfullofcheese, I would limit the results, compare the execution plans and benchmark. Unfortunatelly, too much here depends on the data distribution. But first of all, you should measure somehow how much it takes to return a comparable set of data from a simple `SELECT`. That would be the reference time to strive for.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's the best you can do. i mean at least it's not using nested/multiple queries. you should do a little benchmark on the sql. you could at least limit your results at the least as possible. 15-30 rows for a return set is pretty fine per page (this depends on the app, but 15-30 for me is the tolerance range)

i believe in mySQL (phpMyAdmin, console, GUI whatever) they return some sort of "execution time" which is the time that it took to the query to process. compare that with a benchmark of the query using your server-side code. then compare that with the query run using the server-side code and outputting it with your app interface included after that.

by this, you can see where your bottle-neck is - that is where you optimize.

Comment: I am only ever running this server side, its for data analysis. But I need to run it multiple times (with different variations). Problem is, the query is taking hours. But I am not sure what part is taking so long or if I could do something to speed it along (for example, split it into multiple queries and hold the result in temp tables along the way)

Comment: if this is your only query, i suggest testing in batches, like a few at a time and check the time it took to execute. how many rows does this query return? the problem maybe that you just have a huge haystack of data, and return a huge number of results per query.

Comment: yes, it is going to return 3M rows. Do I just have to be patient?

Comment: 3M rows per query? that's a lot of rows! and saying you need to run it multiple times, that's going to take some time.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the result of your query is input to some other query or system, it is useless to return that much(3M) rows. That would be clever to return just an acceptable amount of rows per query(like 1000) that is for visualizing.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your SQL - the lack of a WHERE clause means it is pulling all rows from:

```
JOIN isi_issues cited_issue ON (cited.issue_id = cited_issue.issue_id)
```

You could look at partitioning the large isi_issues table, this would allow MySQL to perform a bit quicker (smaller files are easier to handle)

Or alternatively you can loop the statement and use a LIMIT clause.

LIMIT 0,100000
then
LIMIT 100001, 200000

This will let the statements run quicker and you can deal with the data in batches.

Comment: I do not think, that using `LIMIT` is a good idea here, since to output rows 100001, 200000 MySQL will need to re-read rows 0, 100000.